# Why does jQuery dead link removal code removes all links?

Tags: jquery

This code checks for dead links. Since 3rd party Ajax requests are not allowed by browsers, I created a php file to check for dead links and my native jQuery code is:

```
function UrlExists(urlx) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/chk.php?url=" + encodeURIComponent(urlx),
        cache: false,
        method: 'get',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.indexOf("T") != -1) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table[id^='row']").each(function () {
        if (!UrlExists($(this).find("a[href$='mp3']").attr('href'))) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    })
});
```

While, I have made sure that

1) `chk.php` is working properly and return `T` on some URLs and on others not.

2) Old JS code is not being used

Still the problem is that above program removes all links. I also tried setting `async` to false but it does'nt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you return within you success-callback, that return will not reach the outer function, thus `UrlExist()` does not return anything as it is written today.

You will either have to do the remove from within your success-callback, or call another function that remove the link, but that function would still have to be called from within your success-callback.

Comment: Yes, otherwise you won't have access to the proper element from within that function.

Answer (score 2):

The success callback is called by jQuery, and it consumes the return value. UrlExists in your code always and invariably returns the undefined value, which is considered false. Try something like this below:

```
function urlExists(url, callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/chk.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(url),
        cache: false,
        method: 'get',
        success: function(data){
            if (data.indexOf("T") != -1){
                callback(true);
            } else {
                callback(false);
            }
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table[id^='row']").each(function() {
        var url = $(this).find("a[href$='mp3']").attr('href');
        var self = this;
        urlExists(url, function (exists) {
            if (! exists) {
                $(self).remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Or you can write the urlExists using the synchronous method described in other answers, however it makes the javascript engine block for the duration of each fetch, and furthermore is slower as multiple requests cannot happen simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are async. Therefore a return within the object doesn't work properly (or not at all).

You need a callback function

```
function Urlexists(urlx,callback){

    [..]
    if(data.indexOf("T") != -1){
        callback(true);
    }
    [..]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had the same code in plain javascript before and it was synchronous. In jQuery, it would be:

```
return $.ajax({
    url: "/chk.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(urlx),
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    method: 'get'
}).responseText.indexOf("T") > -1;
```

This is if you just wanted to swap that code out for jQuery. If you also wanted to make it asynchronous, you have to do the removing in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX call is asynchronous (the first A in AJAX), so the function returns before the answer from the server arrives.

Do the removal in the success callback function:

```
function UrlExists(urlx, element) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/chk.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(urlx),
    cache: false,
    method: 'get',
    success: function(data){
      if(data.indexOf("T") == -1){
        element.remove();
      }
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table[id^='row']").each(function(){
    UrlExists($(this).find("a[href$='mp3']").attr('href')), $(this))
  })
});
```

Comment: hmm, though now the function name is misleading.

Comment: Its confusing, I thought the problem was that value is being returned is consumed the success callback. How does being Async comes into play?

Comment: @Shubham: The AJAX call being asynchronous means that the request is sent to the server, and the `$.ajax` function call returns immediately. When the response arrives from the server, the success callback function runs. The return value from the success function can't be used as return value for the `UrlExists` function, because it has already finished.